# How to make DRF pass query parameters to the actions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using filtering in the django rest framework using django-filters. Due to the nature of some @actions I have on my viewset, I need the filter parameters to be passed to these actions. Is there any way to pass the query parameters of the current listview of a viewset to these actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by overwriting the default django-rest-framework renderers and changing `get_extra_actions` method to reflect the urls with the correct query parameters.

```
def get_extra_actions(extra_actions_dict, view):
    query_params = view.request.query_params
    for k, v in extra_actions_dict.items():
        extra_actions_dict[k] = f'{v}?{urlencode(query_params, doseq=True)}'
    return extra_actions_dict


class BrowsableAPIRenderer(RestBrowsableAPIRenderer):
    def get_extra_actions(self, view, status_code):
        extra_actions_dict = super(BrowsableAPIRenderer, self).get_extra_actions(view, status_code)
        return get_extra_actions(extra_actions_dict, view)
```